# Resizing/Scaling fonts in inner container

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'd like to be able to increase the default font-size, but only within a certain DIV.

Obviously, this seems like *exactly* the sort of case that `ems` were meant for.  My problem is I *only* want to increase the font-size, without affecting other things that are sized with `em`, like padding and margins.

This might seem like an odd use case, or perhaps I'm just "doing it wrong™".  My use case here is essentially as follows:

I have a website that is displaying a chart containing tabular data.  The chart can be viewed in two modes, summary mode and full mode.  Summary mode shows a smaller version of the chart, with many data omitted.  The "full" version shows everything, and takes up almost the width of the browser window.

I'd like to be able to use the same style sheet for both versions.  But the "full" version should probably have a larger font-size.  However, the "full" version (and just about every module aligned on the left side of the screen) has a certain left padding, which keeps all text aligned the same distance from the left edge of the screen.

If I wrap the "full" version chart in a DIV that simply increases the base `em`, it will also increase the padding, thus making the data in the chart not left-aligned with everything else on the screen.

So...

1. What are some solutions to increase the font-size without increasing padding?
2. Am I "doing this wrong" somehow - is it a mistake to use `em` units for things like padding or margins?

Comment: *increase the font-size, without affecting other things that are sized with em* ... will be impossible since em is calculated based on that value

Comment: Danko's right. If you use `em`s in the following: `div { font-size: 16px; padding: 1em; }` then that padding will always be tied to the element's declared or inherited `font-size`. Change the `padding` (etc) to fixed-widths or perhaps use `rem`s instead to be relative to the `<body>` `font-size` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rem` instead of `em` for `padding`s for example in your case, as it is not affected by the changes of other elements in the page, as it is based on the root font-size of your page (html if I remember well).

Good reading here : https://j.eremy.net/confused-about-rem-and-em/